# Best way to sanitize a multiple choice select list

Tags: php, mysql

I’m aware of the benefits of using MySQLi and PDO, but nevertheless I’m wondering what the best way to sanitize a multiple choice select list is out of the following options:

Firstly the obvious method using mysql_real_escape_string:

```
$clean_POST = array();
$clean_POST = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['foo']);
```

But is there a risk that a malicious user could send through numerous POST values and manage to block up the server? The replies [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8719061/php-could-automatically-processing-every-post-variable-be-a-security-issue) seem to suggest this is a possibility.

This issue could be mitigated by creating a whitelist and iterating over it checking for exact matches in the POST:

```
$_POST['foo'] = array('a', 'b');
$whitelist = array(‘a’, 'b', 'c', 'd');
$clean_POST = array();

if (isset($_POST['foo']))
    {
    foreach ($whitelist as $value)
        {
        if (in_array($value, $_POST['foo']))
            {
            $clean_POST[] = $value;
            }
        }
    }
```

But compared to the mysql-real-escape-string method is there likely to be a significant processing time disadvantage using this approach, particularly where there are numerous fields which need to be processed concurrently?

Could one method be regarded as superior considering both security and performance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Performance vs security is inappropriate in many programming contexts. Most likely your input checking will result in a database update or insert query which will take from 100 to 1000s of time longer than your "complex" input check.

Consider that in 1 (2,5,20) years time you or someone else will work on your code, having no idea why or if something was done. Best practice is to check against a set of allowed entries, otherwise you wouldn't have a drop down list. Also, between the display of the dropdown list and the form submission this value list may have changed, hence again you need to check against it.

All major frameworks check exactly this way, so sooner or later you will come to the same conclusion.

Comment: Good answer. There is indeed some relatively heavy querying going on after sanitization so it sounds like relatively speaking the latter is unlikely to amount to a significant performance drag. That said I might try some benchmarking just to satisfy my curiosity.

Answer (score 1):

Common suggestion will be: *apply sanitizing only where it's needed and only according to context, where it's needed*. I.e. : will all your POST be a part of some query? If not, then you'll need to sanitize only those parts, which will be used in query.

Now, about your supposed disadvantage - to be sure, that it will be, you should do measures. There are many cases when checking whitelist will be faster than applying escaping function. And in your specific case the best way to figure that out - is to measure. Whitelist in general is the most powerful tool to secure your fields - because you'll be sure that nothing can overcome them and be passed further to your application. So, I suggest - if you know exactly limited set of allowed values - use that set as a whitelist.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers, not a bad idea to do some benchmarking to check relative performance.